# Set border TextView not in in Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, textview, border

I create xml file to set background for TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/home_replay_bt_background" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

and in main_acitivity.xml I set for textview :

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_textview_notify"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/notify"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="11sp" />
```

and it run in more device but in android 4.2.2 it show oval boder not show rectangle border for textview.
How I can fix it? thank you verymuch!
screen in other device[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDbAd.png)

in android 4.2.2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZWL3.png)

Comment: please share the screenshot

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I added my screen. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The oval effect maybe due to the small screen resolution of your 4.2.2 device. Reduce the corner radius and try again.

Comment: thank you, I tried with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:shape="rectangle"> <solid android:color="@color/home_replay_bt_background" /> <corners android:radius="30dp" /> </shape> and it ok

Answer (score 0):

1.use stroke instead of corner like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@color/home_replay_bt_background" />
           <stroke android:color=#ffffff
            android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Comment: thank you, I tried with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/home_replay_bt_background" />
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
and it ok